# Before the fft2, why need fftshift for the kernel?

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution, image-processing

When I study some paper, I have some questions about usase of convolution theorem.

```
Laplacian  = [0 1 0;1 -4 1;0 1 0];
F = padarray(Laplacian,[m-3+1,n-3+1]/2,'pre');
F = padarray(W,[m-3-1,n-3-1]/2,'post');
```

F : filter

From this, first I want use convolution theorem :

```
fft2(image).*fft2(F).
```

But, in the reference, the method is used like :

```
fft2(image).*fft2(fftshift(F)).
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the FFT, the origin is in the top-left corner, not in the middle of the image.

If you create a kernel and pad it such that the origin is in the middle of the image, then compute the FFT, you will have the FFT of a *shifted* kernel. Applying this will shift your result image too.

You need to use `ifftshift`, not `fftshift`, to shift the kernel’s origin to the top-left pixel. `fftshift` shifts the origin from the top-left back to the middle. The two functions produce the same result on an even-sized image, but not on an odd-sized one.

Comment: thanks. it helped a lot.